# facebook api returns 0 on getUser method even when logged in

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

i have the following set of code:

```
<?php
require("facebook.php");
require("settings.php");
$facebook=new Facebook(array('appId'=>$app_id,'secret'=>$secret,'cookie'=>true));
$user=$facebook->getUser();
if($user)
{
    var_dump($user);
    $logout_url=$facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    echo "<a href='$logout_url'>logout</a>";
    //logged in...
}
else
{
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope"=>"read_mailbox,publish_stream"));
    echo "<a href='$login_url'>Login</a>";
    //not logged in...
}
?>
```

even when i am logged in, the getUser is returning 0, i saw somewhere doing a page refresh would work but in my case, it is not working too... and when i checked my cookie, only session id is being set, and no any other cookie is being set, what may be the problem? waiting for solution...

Comment: Have you logged in through the URL `$login_url`? And you need to specify `'redirect_uri'` in `getLoginUrl()`

Answer (score 0):

The newest SDK no longer requires `'cookie'=>true` so you should update the SDK, the cause of your problem is most likely the certificate error that occurred in a previous revision of the SDK.